# Firefox extension dissapears from extensions folder

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm trying to develop a Firefox extension. I've created a new profile, and I copy the folder of my extension to the `extensions` folder, with Firefox not running. When I run Firefox, I see how the folder of my extension disappears from the `extensions` folder, and Firefox opens without the extension. I've also tried to make a link, a text file called exactly same than the extension's `em:id`, with the path of the folder inside. However, the same thing happens every time - the file disappears when starting Firefox. I'm working on Firefox 14, Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first install the extension into firefox. For that, make xpi file of your source, install it to firefox and restart it. Once the extension is installed, you can start editing source files inside the extension folder. Before making the xpi, make sure that your `install.rdf` have `<em:unpack>true</em:unpack>` to force firefox to unpack your xpi. **Unpacking is not recommended and may cause performance issues.**

My preferred method is to use [Firefox extension proxy file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Firefox_extension_proxy_file) where you can keep your source code anywhere and still enjoy the same benefit.